# How to hit the "run" button after starting up thonny automatically after boot to Desktop GUI

Tags: python

I try to hit the `run` button after opening the "thonny python ide" successfully with the following adjustments in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@thonny /usr/bin/home/pi/Dekstop/cao.py
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
```

Has anyone an idea how I can do that manually in autostart?
I am asking for this different way to start a python script because I have tried everything else with rc.local etc.

Comment: Bad idea running a program permanently in Thonny. It adds an extra layer of complexity that can cause problems. Why can’t you run the Python program on its own?

Comment: Have you also got a typo - Dekstop / Desktop ?

Comment: @CoderMike because I developed it in thonny and do not know how to make it run elsewhere

Comment: @CoderMike what is a typo Desktop / Desktop?

Comment: Thonny just runs the python executable behind the scenes.  From a command line, try this:  ```python3 /usr/bin/home/pi/Dekstop/cao.py```  and see if that starts your program the way you want.

Comment: You can simulate keyboard/mouse events using [xdotool](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60859/33476), but your time will be better spent learning how to write standalone scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I am assuming that your program cao.py is actually locate in /home/pi/Desktop

Your question appears to have the path wrong and the Desktop folder spelt wrong.

I've create the following simple program as an example:

```
import time
print('cao')
time.sleep(10)
```

To run this program on its own open a 'Terminal' window and use:

```
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/cao.py
```

[image]

If you want this to start automatically from /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart add the following to the autostart file:

```
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/Desktop/cao.py
```

If you want this to start automatically from /etc/rc.local add the following to the rc.local file before 'exit 0':

```
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/cao.py >> /home/pi/log.txt 2>&1 &
```

This will output any print or error messages to log.txt

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are right, I have added too much on the Desktop path. Can you tell me what the difference is between rc.local and @lxterminal? I have tried it with @lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/Desktop/cao.py and it did work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Starting a program in rc.local will run the program as root user, not pi. You also won't see the output unless piping to a file like this example. Using @lxterminal in autostart will open a Terminal window then run the program, so you can see the output.